# split a string having numbers of max characters possible in a td

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
var string = "mario rossi laureato";
```

and I have only 15 characters available to write in a td of a table.

so the expected results should be this:

```
<td id="firstTD">mario rossi</td> //this td has 15 characters available
<td id="secondTD">laureato</td>
```

fifteenth place intersects the word "laureato", so it's calculated the excess , and takes the previous word.

another example:

```
var string2 = "hello my name is Paolo"
```

so the expected results should be this:

```
<td id="firstTD">hello my name</td> //this td has 15 characters available
<td id="secondTD">is Paolo</td>
```

fifteenth place intersects the word "is", so it's calculated the excess , and takes the previous word.

Guys any idea about this?

Comment: Someone asked how to do this in PHP, but I offered a [CSS-only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434091/add-if-string-is-too-long-php/11434149#11434149) solution that worked well for them. Main reason being, consider the difference in size between "lllllllllllllll" and "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"

Comment: Maybe splitting the string on spaces, the looping until the length + num of words - 1 is more than 15, then taking everything before that point as string 1?

Comment: @All the answers below, PLEASE READ THE QUESTION, HE WANTS TO ENSURE HE DOESN'T SPLIT WORDS, IF YOU ARE USING AN INDISCRIMINATE SUBSTRING YOUR ANSWER IS WRONG!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zh8RR/

```
// Sample string, to make it easy to see the cut points I've use 1-15 in hex to give us a nice easy way to see the breaks
var string = "1234567 9ABCDE 12345 7 89AB 123456 89ABC E 12 45 789A CD 123";

// Break input string up into words
var parts = string.split(' ');
var sections = [""];
var rows = 0;
// For each word
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    // If it makes the section too long push it to the next section:
    if (sections[rows].length + parts[i].length + 1 > 15) {
        rows++;
    }
    // If we have no text initialise it to be the current word
    if(!sections[rows]) {
        sections[rows] = parts[i];
    } else {
        // Otherwise use a space as a separator and concat them.
        sections[rows] += " " + parts[i];
    }
}
// Write them out to a sample div so we can check.
$('div').html(sections.join("<br />"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
var str = "mario rossi laureato";
var strArr = str.match(/.{1,15}/g);
console.log(strArr.length);
for(var s=0,slen=strArr.length; s < slen; s++) {
    console.log(strArr[s]);
    //create td and append or append strArr[s] to existing td
}
```