# Limit Character in a table

Tags: php, html

Thanks to stackoverflow and its great solution, I have found a way to limit the characters in a table but it doesn't work for me. I tried a lot but with no success.

**This is my table**

```
<?php


$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM library ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");

echo "<table class='table-fill' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th position='fixed' overflow='hidden' width='10%'>Book Name</th> 
<th width='5%'></th>


</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='2' style='padding-bottom: 0;'><a href='library.details.php?id=". $row['id']."' target='content' class='positiontitle-link'><font style='text-shadow: none; font-weight: 800;'>" . $row['bookname']. "</td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo "<tr style='border-top-width: 0; padding-top: 0;'>";
echo '<td style="max-height: 10px;">' . $str . '</td>';

echo "<td style=' padding-top: 0; padding-left: 15px; width: 40%;'> <font color='gray'>Author :</font> " .($row['authorname'] ). "</td>";
echo "<td  width='5%' style=' padding-top: 0;'> <font color='gray'>Year Published </font>" . $row['yearpublished'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

if (strlen($row['bookname']) > 1) $str = substr($row['bookname'], 0, 1) . "..."; 

}
echo"</table>";
?>
```

***This is how it looks like***

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfIYq.jpg]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What *should* it look like?

Comment: Thanks Niet, it should look like this http://i.imgur.com/7dM2D8c.jpg

Comment: Well you put `strlen($row['bookname']) > 1` - you're limiting your string to one character. Pretty sure that's not what you intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add ... if string is too long PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434091/add-if-string-is-too-long-php/11434149#11434149)

Comment: thanks niet, i wanted to test

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It's not a duplicate of the question your referring to. The TS successfully managed the limit the chars, but his html code generation isn't ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing this out of my head so forgive me any format issues and such...

- Move the string length check to just under the while.
- Overwrite $row['bookname'] instead of creating $str.
- Remove the line with:

  ```
  echo '<td style="max-height: 10px;">' . $str . '</td>';
  ```

Result:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
if (strlen($row['bookname']) > 9) $row['bookname'] = substr($row['bookname'], 0, 9) . "..."; 

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='2' style='padding-bottom: 0;'><a href='library.details.php?id=". $row['id']."' target='content' class='positiontitle-link'><font style='text-shadow: none; font-weight: 800;'>" . $row['bookname']. "</td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo "<tr style='border-top-width: 0; padding-top: 0;'>";


echo "<td style=' padding-top: 0; padding-left: 15px; width: 40%;'> <font color='gray'>Author :</font> " .($row['authorname'] ). "</td>";
echo "<td  width='5%' style=' padding-top: 0;'> <font color='gray'>Year Published </font>" . $row['yearpublished'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: can you please explain me the code that what does first 9 means and the second 9.

Comment: I set it to 9 to keep the first 9 chars of the book name. You've chosen 1 in your code. Change it to the number of chars you wish to keep.