# Getting just the first 20 characters

Tags: php

How am I able to turn my string into only 20 characters long?

`<?php print htmlspecialchars_decode($artist, 0, 20, "...");  ?>`

Currently the code above displays an error.

```
<b>Warning</b>:  htmlspecialchars_decode() expects at most 2 parameters, 4 given in <b>/some/domain/path/some-file.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
```

How can I get around this error but still use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` with 20 character long title?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add ... if string is too long PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434091/add-if-string-is-too-long-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
print substr(htmlspecialchars_decode($artist), 0, 20);
```

Also see in the docs: [substr()](http://php.net/substr)

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply separate functions for that, [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

```
$short_artist = htmlspecialchars_decode($artist);
if (strlen($short_artist) > 20) {
    $short_artist = substr($short_artist, 0, 17) . "...";
}
```

If the three dots can make the total 23 characters long, then change the 17 to 20.

Comment: @cale_b this answer would also work, but the other guy answered first and his answer works also..

Comment: @Ritzy - this is the correct answer because it actually is full-featured.  It's NOT the same answer as the other answer.