# how to change large text "Hereisthelargetextbreakwithphp" to "Hereisthelarge..."?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

change large text "Hereisthelargetextbreakwithphp" to "Hereisthelarge..."

```
$string = "Hereisthelargetextbreakwithphp";
$string = strip_tags($string);
if (strlen($string) > 21) {
    $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 21);
    echo $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... '; 
}else{
    echo $string;
}
```

but its nor working for it replace whole this text to "..."

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dynamicguy/3272470

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add ... if string is too long PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434091/add-if-string-is-too-long-php)

Answer (score 0):

When there is no space, strrpos returns false which cast to zero in substr function. That results in that substr return empty string

```
if (strlen($string) > 21) {
    $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 21);
    // If threre is no space in string take it all
    $i = (($i = strrpos($stringCut, ' ')) === false)  ? strlen($stringCut) : $i;
    echo $string = substr($stringCut, 0, $i).'... '; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $string = strip_tags("Hereisthelargetextbreakwithphp");
 echo (strlen($string) > 14) ? substr($string, 0, 14).'... ' : $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Hereisthelargetextbreakwithphp";
echo $string = (strlen($string) > 21) ? (substr($string, 0, 21)."....") : $string;
```

I have used `ternary operator` you can read more about `ternary operator` at https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator

Answer (score 0):

No need to make custom function, as you are using Codeigniter, you can use text helper directly,

Load the helper first,

```
$this->load->helper('text');
```

Then use `character_limiter` function which is already built in,

```
$string = character_limiter($stringCut, 21);
```

And if you want to add `...` after string,

```
$string = character_limiter($stringCut, 21) . '...';
```

Reference: [Codeigniter Text Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html)