# Add ellipses only if longer

Tags: php, html, url, substring, ellipse

I use the following code for hyperlinks:

```
echo "<a href=\"http://".$row['website']."\" target=\"_blank\">".substr($row['website'],0,50).'…'."</a>";
```

This will short the displayed URL if to long and add a trailing `…`. But I want `…` only added if URL longer than declared value, in this case 50 characters.

What's the simples way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add ... if string is too long PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434091/add-if-string-is-too-long-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mb_strimwidth`:

```
echo "<a href=\"http://".$row['website']."\" target=\"_blank\">".mb_strimwidth($row['website'], 0, 50, '…')."</a>";
```

This will ensure the maximum length of the string is 50 characters and add '…' if it exceeds that.

Comment: @user7128548 No problemo ;)