# How can I truncate string values that are too long?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've got array list:

```
$myarray = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'File name 1 - type.zip',
        'size' => '600KB',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'File name 2 - type.pdf',
        'size' => '1.5MB',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'File name 3 - type.jpeg',
        'size' => '50.5KB',
    ),
);
```

. . . and need to truncate the file names, but keep extensions and size of files.

So for example `'File name 1 - type.zip'` should be displayed as `'File name 1 - ... .zip (600KB)'`.

Any tips?

Comment: just do string substring and grab last 25 characters or however many you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I updated your question and title to make it match what you are trying to do a little closer, which will make it more likely for you to get an answer that can help you and others. Feel free to clarify more, if you think I have misrepresented your issue.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to separate the name from the extension. Then there are various ways to shorten and add the ellipsis. The method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434091/add-if-string-is-too-long-php) is very straightforward. You can map this method over your array to format all of the items.

```
$max = 11;

$formatted = array_map(function($file) use ($max) {
    $info = pathinfo($file['name']);
    $name = $info['filename'];
    $name = strlen($name) > $max ? substr($name, 0, $max) . '...' : $name;
    return "$name$info[extension] $file[size]";
}, $myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use explode and substr 
assuming that your len_you_neen is 6 char

```
$tmpArray = explode('.',$myArray['name']);
$myStr = substr($tmpArray[0], 0, 6);

$resultStr = $myStr . '.'.$tmpArray[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give something like below a try. It doesn't include the filesize but I'm sure you can take it from there.

```
$fileName = "File name 1 - type.zip";
echo shortenFileNameWhileMaintainingExtension($fileName);

function shortenFileNameWhileMaintainingExtension($fileName, $shortenToLength = 20) {
    $extension = substr(strrchr($fileName, '.'), 1);
    if((strlen($fileName) - strlen($extension)) < $shortenToLength) {
        return $fileName;
    }
    $newFileName = trim(substr($fileName, 0, $shortenToLength)) . "...." . $extension;
    return $newFileName;
}
```