# File name too long while uploading image in database

Tags: php, file-upload

I have written a line of codes to upload an image in the database, however, trying to upload image gives me this error

> File name too long

Following is my code to upload an image to database:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
    {
      $pid          = rand(1000,9000);
      $title        = $_POST['title'];
      $descpt       = $_POST['description'];
      $push         = isset($_POST['send_push']) ? $_POST['send_push'] : "";
      $feature_image = array();
      $fy           = $_POST['fy'];

      if(empty($title) || empty($descpt) || empty($fy))
      {
          array_push($this->errors, MEND_FIELD_ERROR);
          return;
      }

      if(!empty($_FILES['feature_image']['name'][0]))
      {
          $image = $_FILES['feature_image'];
          $allowed_ext = array('jpeg','jpg','png','pdf','docx');
          $allowed_size = 20000000;

          foreach($image['name'] as $pos=>$image_name)
          {
              $dir = "./cdn/uploads/notice/".$title;      
              $tmp = $image['tmp_name'][$pos];
              $img_size = $image['size'][$pos];
              $img_error = $image['error'][$pos];
              $img_ext = explode('.', $image_name);
              $img_name = $img_ext[0];
              $img_ext = strtolower(end($img_ext));


              if(in_array($img_ext, $allowed_ext))
              {
                  if($img_size <= $allowed_size)
                  {
                    if(!file_exists($dir))
                    {
                        mkdir($dir);
                    }
                    $image_new_name = $img_name.'$$'.uniqid('', true).'.'.$img_ext;

                    $upload_destination = $dir.'/'.$image_new_name;
                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $upload_destination))
                    {
                        array_push($feature_image, $image_new_name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        array_push($this->errors, $img_error);
                        return;
                    }

                  }
              }
              else
              {
                array_push($this->errors, $img_ext.' is not an allowed file extension.');
                return;
              }
          }
      }

      $s_feature_image = json_encode($feature_image, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

      $statement = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `notice` (`pid`,`title`,`descpt`,`date`,`photo`,`fy`)
      VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");         
      if($statement->execute([$pid,$title,$descpt,DAT, $s_feature_image, $fy]))
      {
        if($push == "checked")
        {

            $descpt = strip_tags($descpt);
            $tek = array("message"=>$descpt,"title"=>$title);

            $tokens = $this->getTokens();
            $this->push_notification($tokens,$tek);

        }
        ExitThis::send_to(URL.'notice?id='.$pid);

      }
      else
      {
          array_push($this->errors, DATABASE_ERROR);
          return;
      }
    }
```

Is it because of permission issue or something else? If so, what is causing me this problem and how do I fix this?

Comment: What is the name of the file you are trying to upload or how long is it?

Comment: code working with small file name?

Comment: i think it's due to apache

Comment: When you have an argument i mean filename longer then 255 chars, apache will check this against your file system limits.

Comment: @I'L'l I am trying to upload file in Nepali character and it is खुम्बु पासाङल्हामु गाउँपालिका वडा नं ३ मा सुद्ध तथा पिउनयोग्य खानेपानी योजनाको उद्घाटन सम्पन्न भएको छ ।/water$$5c5bef4455e4c2.23467901.jpg.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448715/limit-file-name-before-uploading-to-server-in-php-html-and-javascript

Comment: i don't know the caracter encoding of nepali language , but put it in the firt param instead of the empty one bellow$ and  try to convert the filename with : $filename = iconv("", "utf-8", $filename);

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI the length of the characters are 138 only.

Comment: How many characters of a folder can function mkdir() make?

Comment: @Alisha - the `strlen` value is 213 though

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI can we extend the length of characters of MySQL?

Comment: @Alisha , i don't get what you mean

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI you were saying that apache will only allow 255 characters so I am asking if I could extend the characters length in apache or not.

Comment: take a see here : https://serverfault.com/questions/120397/max-length-of-url-257-characters-for-mod-rewrite

Answer (score -1):

this is how I upload the file into the server and save the file name + extension into the database.

```html
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$imgFile = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
$imgSize = $_FILES['photo']['size'];

$folder = 'images/'; // upload directory
$imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
// valid image extensions
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
// rename uploading image
$img = rand(1000, 1000000) . "." . $imgExt;
// allow valid image file formats
if (in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)) {
    // Check file size '5MB'
    if ($imgSize < 5000000) {
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $folder . $img);
    } else {
        $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    }
} else {
    $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
}

$query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `profile` SET `photo` = '$img' WHERE `id` = '$id'");

if ($query) {
 echo "<script>alert('Profile Updated'); window.location ='index.php?data=profile' </script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Failed'); window.location ='index.php?data=profile' </script>";
}

?>
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. Read OP's question again and check the comments.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this code and possibly even more. Whilst the temp file won't be uploaded due to failing validation, you still insert it into the database, both `$imgExt` and `$id` are vulnerable. You should never trust client data