# How to short wordpress post url text length if using in header?

Tags: php, wordpress, html

Below are the code of wp post that show latest single post link in header. but post url text getting overlap, So please suggest how to modify below code to show first few word of post.

```
<?php$recentPosts = new WP_Query();
$recentPosts->query('showposts=1'); while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) :

$recentPosts->the_post();?>


<div><strong>What's Hot :</strong> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

<?php the_title(); ?></a></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You can get one example Here - codyplay.com

**Thanks**

Comment: Check this. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75691/limit-the-word-count-in-the-post-title
You can use that function instead of "the_title()" in your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434149/2593099